# game mod security question

Tags: c++, architecture, python, client-server, security

So I'm in the process of building a game in C++ for the engine and Python for behavior and moddability. One of the planned major features is that when the game client connects to a game server with mods, the server will tell the client where to get the mods. This introduces a security problem for the client as a mod with malicious code could be downloaded. How can I limit python so that mods can not affect the system outside of the game?

Comment: Broad for sure, but this brings up some good concerns. I hope to see some answers to this.

Comment: this may not be exactly what you're going for, but you might want to look into using some way of limiting mod file access. Maybe look into using [PhysicsFS](http://icculus.org/physfs/), which claims to be designed for running untrusted scripts (although I have not personally used it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've researched this same issue, but for a different platform.  What you're looking for is called a "sandbox."

https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython